# How do you access flags passed in through the command line in Node?

Tags: node.js

I know that you could access them in `process.argv`. Ex.

```
~/code/study-buddies $ node server/app.js --dev
[ 'node',
  '/Users/azerner/code/study-buddies/server/app.js',
  '--dev' ]
```

But is this the best practice? What if you want to access an array of all the flags, but not the normal command line arguments?

Comment: Flags are just like any other command line argument; it's how the program parses and interprets them that gives the flags special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best practice" is a relative question and I'm not sure what you mean by "the normal command line arguments" but some good stuff can be found in what other people have done in the past.

For example, you can look at [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) to see one way that arguments are handled.  The initial example is pretty simple: you pass the `argv` array into the module and it parses what it receives.

`var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));`

The module [loops through](https://github.com/substack/minimist/blob/master/index.js#L88) the argument array, parsing it out and building an object that can then be used without worrying quite so much about the fiddly bits of argv parsing.

Other modules, like node-getopt and commander.js provide a ton more functions, but in the end they are also relying upon `argv`

Comment: Thank you, that's useful to know. The real answer I was looking for was Colonel Thirty Two's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596267/how-do-you-access-flags-passed-in-through-the-command-line-in-node#comment51144252_31596267) - I hadn't known that that was true.

Comment: This repo is now available at: https://github.com/minimistjs/minimist

Answer (score 0):

You can find [many libraries in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/args) to parse your argv (turn options into key-value maps, separate options from positional arguments, do validation, etc.). I found [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to be nice and easy to use.